# Issues with numlk key shortcut

Tags: 16.04

My Asus Laptop doesn't come with a numlk key and the shortcut given by Asus does not work (im assuming because i changed from the default windows 10 to linux) anyone have any ideas what else might work?

Comment: You mean it works in Windows and not in Ubuntu? What is the shortcut (is there any documentation for that)?

Comment: I only recently needed to use it so i never found out if it worked for windows, the shortcut is fn+insert and there is documentation throughout their website and manual that states so

Comment: Any advice? @Melebius

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have no experience with it.